# Python: storing/retrieving/updating a large number of arbitrary objects

Tags: python, pickle

I have several million records I want to store, retrieve, delete pretty frequently. Each of these records has a "key", but the "value" is not easily translatable to a dictionary as it is an arbitrary Python object returned from a module method that I didn't write (I understand that a lot of hierarchical data structures like `json` work better as dictionaries, and not sure if `json` is the preferred database in any case).

I am thinking to pickle each entry in a separate file. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module.

You can use it as a dictionary, much like in `json`, but it stores objects using pickle.

From the python official docs:

```
import shelve

d = shelve.open(filename) # open -- file may get suffix added by low-level
                          # library

d[key] = data   # store data at key (overwrites old data if
                # using an existing key)
data = d[key]   # retrieve a COPY of data at key (raise KeyError if no
                # such key)
del d[key]      # delete data stored at key (raises KeyError
                # if no such key)
flag = d.has_key(key)   # true if the key exists
klist = d.keys() # a list of all existing keys (slow!)

# as d was opened WITHOUT writeback=True, beware:
d['xx'] = range(4)  # this works as expected, but...
d['xx'].append(5)   # *this doesn't!* -- d['xx'] is STILL range(4)!

# having opened d without writeback=True, you need to code carefully:
temp = d['xx']      # extracts the copy
temp.append(5)      # mutates the copy
d['xx'] = temp      # stores the copy right back, to persist it

# or, d=shelve.open(filename,writeback=True) would let you just code
# d['xx'].append(5) and have it work as expected, BUT it would also
# consume more memory and make the d.close() operation slower.

d.close()       # close it
```

Comment: So it would pickle everything to a single file?

Answer (score 1):

I would evaluate the use of a key/value database like berkeleydb, kyoto cabinet or others. This will give you all the fancy things plus a better handling of disk space. In a filesystem with a block size of 4096B, one million files occupy ~4GB whatever is the size of your objects (as lower bound limit, if the objects are larger than 4096B the the size increase).